# How do I improve the diction?

Tags: word-choice, diction

The sentence is as follows:

"Knowing these truths and yet not knowing how to make my voice heard was torturous."

What I am trying to convey is that I knew about certain things (i.e truths) but didn't know how to make people listen to me and understand, and this was driving my crazy.

I feel that the whole sentence is not as clear as it could be and using the word torturous just seems weird.

Any ideas on how to improve it?

Any comment would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Seyed

Comment: Well, start by replacing _torturous_; you're right, it's an awful choice. You were there, you decide what adjective is correct. Next, move that extraheavy subject to the end of the sentence with Extraposition: _It was `Adjective` knowing these truths, and yet ... heard._

Comment: I would remove "and" and substitute "maddening" for "torturous".

Comment: Thanks @JohnLawler :) Personally what adjective would you believe suitable?

Comment: Or possibly 'infuriating'.  Or even, more informally, 'hell'.

Comment: I think this is "writing advice". But if OP wants to stick close to his original wording, I'd suggest changing ***tortuous*** to ***sheer torture***, since the former would normally be understood to mean *twisting, winding, curving, curvy, bending, sinuous, meandering...*

Comment: @user129715: You're welcome. As to choosing adjectives, I wasn't there, so I don't have any idea what it felt like. And, FF, I gave grammar advice, please. Writing doesn't enter into it, except that a sentence as clunky as the original would never have come out of anybody's mouth.  When I encountered a sentence like this and had the author in class, I would ask them what it was supposed to mean. They invariably answered in several short clear sentences. I told them to write down what they had said, instead of what they had written.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you so much for the help! Are you an English professor?

Comment: @user129715: No. I've taught in English departments, and I've taught ESL and writing, but I've been a linguistics professor since 1967. One of my specialties is English syntax and semantics.

Comment: Let's ask Cassandra!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions (new choices for the words you want replaced in bold; commentary in italics):

- "Knowing these truths and yet not **being heeded** was **unbearable**."
- "It was **hell** to know these truths and yet not know how to **share them effectively**."
  (*rearranging the structure of the sentence, to avoid the use of gerunds*)
- "I knew these truths, but not how to make others understand them; it was **terrible**."
  (*splitting the sentence into two clauses, again avoiding the use of gerunds*)